# Flash components in player shows blue selection brackets

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i'm making a simple quiz with Flash CC using radioButtons component.
I made a custom skin for the radio Buttons, and all works OK but, when i publish the SWF, the blue selection brackets randomly appears when user clics on the buttons.

Those blue selection brackets are the same you can see when you select something in the Flash user interface, but none is actually selected in any timeline (movieclips, buttons etc..)

Any idea?

Comment: We might need to look at your code for the skin, as well as a png of the problem.

Comment: Sorry but i can't post images, i'm new to this forum!
I don't use any code for the skin...i'm using standard FlashCC RadioButtons component, and i change only graphics inside their skin.